# Why are templatetags stored in directories?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm now working with template tags and one thing I haven't understood is why do template-tags have to be stored inside a `templatetags` directory in the app. Is there an underlying reason for this? Is it possible to store them in a templatetags.py file somehow so that I can reduce the extra bloat around having extra directories?

Comment: I find that having them in a subdirectory helps with separation of unrelated template tags, and also helps avoid potential merge conflicts if using a distributed version control system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django expects you to arrange your apps in certain ways. Requiring a templatetags directory in the app is not the exception. Some other requirements are:

- ModelAdmin in `admin.py` (for autodiscovery)
- Models in `models.py`
- Management commands in `management/commands` directory
- Fixtures in the `fixtures` directory

Unlike templates, where there are hooks to specify how your templates are loaded, there is no easy way to store your templatetags modules in a different location.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the rationale of Alasdair, that the standard django expectation is to have `admin`, `models`, `templates` and `templatetags` all within the respective app folders, I think there is unnecessary boilerplate associated.

I think it is for that reason, that there are plenty of 3rd party apps: https://github.com/ojii/django-classy-tags, https://github.com/justquick/django-native-tags and https://github.com/alex/django-templatetag-sugar to reduce the boiler plate.